# ¿Cómo insertar en un input hidden una imagen que se pasó por compact a a vista en HTML?

Tags: html5, pug, laravel-6

Tengo un proceso de 3 vistas para insertar varias cosas, en la primera vista, se inserta una imagen junto a otros campos de texto en un `form` y la paso por `compact` a la segunda vista.

Las variables de texto sé cómo mostrarlas, pero no he sabido cómo mostrar la imagen ni tampoco ponerla en un `input` de archivo.

Este es mi controlador en donde paso los datos del `form` a la segunda vista:

```html
public function create2(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('data.image');
    
    return view('create2',compact('image'));
}
```

Y mi `pug` (HTML)

```html
form(action='/paso3' method='post')
  @csrf
  label.titleEspecial1 Nombre
  input(type="hidden" name="data[data1]" required value="{{$data[data1]}}")
  input(type="hidden" name="data[data2]" required value="{{$data[data2]}}")
```

Me gustaría desplegar la imagen que pasé por compact y además insertar la imagen en un `input del tipo`hidden`para que se vaya en el`Request`

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estas mezclando conceptos.
Estamos hablando de 3 elementos HTML.

El elemento de tipo imagen (tag `img`) lo usamos para insertar una imagen en un documento HTML de esta forma: `<img src="./public/imgs/foo.jpg">` luego puedes mostrarla o no en la página usando estilos. Los otros dos elementos (*input de tipo hidden* e *input de tipo file*) se usan en formularios, entonces se enviarán al hacer el envío del formulario.

Ahora, ¿quieres mostrar una imagen en la página a partir de los datos que llegan a la vista? La cargas en el elemento `img`. Además, quieres que esa imagen se envie con el formulario, indicas el dato que sea, que puede ser la URI, nombre, etc., aunque dado que ya tienes la imagen en el servidor y guardada su URI asociada a una ID, debería ser su ID, esta la pones en el *input de tipo hidden*, por ejemplo: `<input type="hidden" name="image" value="{{$data[image][id]}}">` o algo parecido.

El *input de tipo file* lo necesitas para la carga inicial de la imagen, es decir seleccionar el fichero del disco en la parte cliente y enviarlo al servidor para tratarla / almacenarla. Ahora, tienes en el controlador:

```
public function create2(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('data.image');

    return view('create2',compact('image'));
}
```

¿Este es el método que recoge la imagen que quieres cargar de disco y enviar a la segunda vista? Pues aquí falta bastante lógica... debes almacenar la imagen en disco y una URI en BD para poder enviarla y mostrarla posteriormente en las vistas.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que con tres pasos/vistas que el usuario debe seguir y no es hasta la última vista en donde hago el guardado de toda la información. El usuario debería poder regresar en las vistas a modificar la información si se arrepiente,  de la manera que me lo comentas estaría guardando todo de nuevo cada vez que retroceda y avance.

Es necesario ir pasando la información, ya sean imágenes o texto, de manera temporal hasta la última vista donde otro método es el cual almacena toda la información en la base de datos, como parte de los requerimientos

Comment: @NoobDev Lo recomendable en ese caso (sino quieres almacenar nada) sería una sola vista, mostrando los inputs a medida que se vayan completando los previos y cargar la imagen vía ajax, para poder mostrarla durante el proceso. Esa la almacenas en un directorio temporal (que vaciarías periódicamente) y la mueves sólo a un directorio definitivo si se completa todo el proceso.